# Snowflake subquery

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have two tables. **Transaction**(ID, TERMINALID) and **Terminal**(ID, TERMINALID, EXPORT_DATE). The goal is to obtain for each row from *Transaction* table newest recored from *Terminal* table. Snowflake is used as a backend.

I have this SQL query:

```
SELECT tr.ID,
       (SELECT te.ID
        FROM "Terminal" te
        WHERE te.TERMINALID = tr.TERMINALID
        ORDER BY te.EXPORT_DATE DESC
        LIMIT 1)
FROM "Transaction" tr;
```

But I get this error:

> SQL compilation error: Unsupported subquery type cannot be evaluated

Error disappears if I replace *tr.TERMINALID* with a specific value. So I can't reference parent table from nested SELECT. Why this is not possible? Query works in MySQL.

Comment: Ist the subquery supposed to be a *scalar* subquery? BTW: add a column alias to the subquery.

Comment: Yes, subquery shoud return one column value from one row. Therefore, there is the LIMIT.

Comment: Please add the table definitions for the tables to your question. (Are the table column names *really* mixed/upper cased?)

Comment: Yes, names are ok. Every column is VARCHAR(16777216) with no primary or unique keys.

Comment: `ERROR:  length for type varchar cannot exceed 10485760` BTW: you dont have to specify a size for varchar().

Comment: Length of varchar is not a problem. It is possible to create varchar column with length 16777216 without any error in Snowflake.

Comment: It is a problem if you attempt to use it in original postgres. Besides, it is not *needed* to specify a size for a varchar column. (and tables without candidate keys are meaningless)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I'm afraid Snowflake doesn't support correlated subqueries of this kind.

You can achieve what you want by using `FIRST_VALUE` to compute best per-terminalid id :

```
-- First compute per-terminalid best id
with sub1 as (
  select 
    terminalid, 
    first_value(id) over (partition by terminalid order by d desc) id
  from terminal 
),
-- Now, make sure there's only one per terminalid id
sub2 as (
  select 
    terminalid, 
    any_value(id) id
  from sub1
  group by terminalid
)
-- Now use that result
select tr.ID, sub2.id
FROM "Transaction" tr
JOIN sub2 ON tr.terminalid = sub2.terminalid
```

You can run subqueries first to see what they do.

We're working on making our support for subqueries better, and possibly there's a simpler rewrite, but I hope it helps.

Comment: Better subquery support would be great, but even better would be a better error message when they aren't supported. If the problem is window functions or result set limits, saying so would be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
tr.ID
  , (SELECT te.ID
     FROM "Terminal" te 
     WHERE te.TERMINALID = tr.TERMINALID
     ORDER BY te.EXPORT_DATE DESC
     LIMIT 1
    ) AS the_id -- <<-- add an alias for the column
FROM "Transaction" tr
    ;
```

---

UPDATE:

- `length for type varchar cannot exceed 10485760`
- just use type `varchar` (or `text`) instead

Works here (with quoted identifiers):

```
CREATE TABLE "Transaction" ("ID" VARCHAR(123), "TERMINALID"  VARCHAR(123)) ;
CREATE TABLE "Terminal" ( "ID"  VARCHAR(123), "TERMINALID"  VARCHAR(123), "EXPORT_DATE" DATE);

SELECT tr."ID"
        , (SELECT te."ID"
        FROM "Terminal" te
        WHERE te."TERMINALID" = tr."TERMINALID"
        ORDER BY te."EXPORT_DATE" DESC
        LIMIT 1) AS meuk
FROM "Transaction" tr
        ;
```

---

BONUS UPDATE: avoid the scalar subquery and use plain old `NOT EXISTS(...)` to obtain the record with the most recent date:

```
SELECT tr."ID"
        , te."ID" AS meuk
FROM "Transaction" tr
JOIN "Terminal" te ON te."TERMINALID" = tr."TERMINALID"
        AND NOT EXISTS ( SELECT *
        FROM "Terminal" nx
        WHERE nx."TERMINALID" = te."TERMINALID"
        AND nx."EXPORT_DATE" > te."EXPORT_DATE"
        )
        ;
```

Comment: Length of varchar is not a problem. It is possible to create varchar column with length 16777216 without any error in Snowflake.

Comment: If you create this stuff (with different table names), and it runs, then varchar size **is** the problem. If it doesn't run then snowflake-datawarehouse is a crippled-down version of postgres.

Comment: I tried to run your SQL. Unfortunately, it doesn't work. Still same error in Snowlake. Thanks for your help anyway.

Comment: You could try to rewrite into row_number() if snowflake-beyond-help supports window functions.

Answer (score 0):

So few years later (2022), some correlated subqueries are support, but not this one:

using this data:

```
WITH transaction(id, terminalid) AS (
    SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (1,10),
    (2,11),
    (3,12)
), terminal(id, terminalid, export_date) AS (
     SELECT * FROM VALUES
    (100, 10, '2022-03-18'::date),
    (101, 10, '2022-03-19'::date),
    (102, 11, '2022-03-20'::date),
    (103, 11, '2022-03-21'::date),
    (104, 11, '2022-03-22'::date),
    (105, 12, '2022-03-23'::date)
)
```

So compared to Marcin's we can now use a QUALIFY to select only one value per `terminalid` in a single step:

```
WITH last_terminal as (
    SELECT id, 
        terminalid
    FROM terminal
    QUALIFY row_number() over(PARTITION BY terminalid ORDER BY export_date desc) = 1
)
SELECT tr.ID,
      te.id
FROM transaction AS tr
JOIN last_terminal AS te 
    ON te.TERMINALID = tr.TERMINALID
ORDER BY 1;
```

giving:

| ID | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 101 |
| 2 | 104 |
| 3 | 105 |

and if you have multiple terminals per day, and terimal.id is incrementing number you could use:

```
QUALIFY row_number() over(PARTITION BY terminalid ORDER BY export_date desc, id desc) = 1
```

Now if your table is not that larger, you can do the JOIN then prune via the QUALIFY, and avoid the CTE, but on large tables this is much less performant, so I would only use this form when doing ad-hoc queries, where swapping forms if viable if performance problems occur.

```
SELECT tr.ID,
      te.id
FROM transaction AS tr
JOIN terminal AS te 
    ON te.TERMINALID = tr.TERMINALID
QUALIFY row_number() over(PARTITION BY tr.id ORDER BY te.export_date desc, te.id desc) = 1    
ORDER BY 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of subquery is currently not supported.

[Working with subqueries - Limitations](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/querying-subqueries.html#limitations):

> **The only type of subquery that allows a LIMIT / FETCH clause is an uncorrelated scalar subquery.** Also, because an uncorrelated scalar subquery returns only 1 row, the LIMIT clause has little or no practical value inside a subquery

---

Query in question is correlated subquery, thus the result.

```
SELECT tr.ID,
       (SELECT te.ID
        FROM "Terminal" te
        WHERE te.TERMINALID = tr.TERMINALID  --correlation
        ORDER BY te.EXPORT_DATE DESC
        LIMIT 1)
FROM "Transaction" tr;
```